# проблемы с "setText" Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пишу программу которая берет данные из excel таблицы и вставляет их в программу, только у меня не получается вставить сами данные, в консоле выводит все хорошо, а в приложении выводит только последнюю строчку из таблицы, подскажите с чем это связано?

вывод из консоли

[image: Вывод из консоли]

вывод в приложении

[image: вывод в приложении]

main файл

```
from UI.table import Ui_table
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
   QStackedWidget, QMessageBox
import openpyxl
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets




class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):




def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self) 
    self.initUI()
    



def initUI(self):
    wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx", data_only=True)
    print(wb.sheetnames)
    wb.active = 0
    sheet = wb.active
    for i in range(1,12):

        table = (sheet['A'+str(i)].value,sheet['B'+str(i)].value,sheet['C'+str(i)].value)
        print(table)
        self.textBrowser.setText(str(table))
        

    


if __name__ == '__main__': 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()

windows = QStackedWidget()

windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  # 0
windows.setWindowTitle("")

windows.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

table файл

```
class Ui_table(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 140, 581, 401))
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 
    4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
    "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
    "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
    "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; 
    font-style:normal;\">\n"
    "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block- 
    indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"></p></body></html>"))
```

Comment: Ну так `setText(str(table))` каждый раз заменяет содержимое текстового виджета.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Метод `setText` заменяет содержимое указанной строкой.

Поэтому можно добавлять текст через `setText`, но помнить про предыдущее значение

```
self.textBrowser.setText(self.textBrowser.toPlainText() + "\n" + str(table))
```

Или использовать `append`:

```
self.textBrowser.append(str(table))
```

Answer (score 1):

Я совсем не понимаю зачем вы закачиваете таблицу в `QTextBrowser` ?

Почувствуйте разницу:

```
import sys
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd                                           # pip install pandas
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, \
   QStackedWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


# from UI.table import Ui_table
class Ui_table(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
#        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(800, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 140, 581, 401))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML \
        4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; \
        font-style:normal;\">\n"
        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"></p></body></html>"))
        

class StartMenuMain(QMainWindow, Ui_table):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(StartMenuMain, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx", data_only=True)
        wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="test_xlsx.xlsx", data_only=True) # !!!
        
        print(wb.sheetnames)
        wb.active = 0
        sheet = wb.active
        for i in range(1, 12):

            table = (sheet['A'+str(i)].value,sheet['B'+str(i)].value,sheet['C'+str(i)].value)
            print(table)
#            self.textBrowser.setText(str(table))                      # ---
            self.textBrowser.append(str(table))                        # +++
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)        

        excel_file_path = 'test_xlsx.xlsx'                              # !!!
        worksheet_name = 'Sheet1'                                       # !!!
        self.loadExcelData(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)
        
    def loadExcelData(self, excel_file_path, worksheet_name):
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, worksheet_name)
        if df.size == 0:
            return

        df.fillna('', inplace=True)
        self.table.setRowCount(df.shape[0])
        self.table.setColumnCount(df.shape[1])
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(df.columns)

        # returns pandas array object
        for row in df.iterrows():
            values = row[1]
            for col_index, value in enumerate(values):
                if isinstance(value, (float, int)):
                    value = '{0:0,.0f}'.format(value)
                tableItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(value))
                self.table.setItem(row[0], col_index, tableItem)

        self.table.setColumnWidth(2, 300)
                

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    startmenu_window = StartMenuMain()
    windows = QStackedWidget()
    windows.addWidget(startmenu_window)  # 0
    windows.setWindowTitle("")
    windows.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я просто не знал как это реализовать, спасибо, я не так давно начал учить pyqt5

Comment: @grabhar пожалуйста. Так почему вы не спросили то , что вам надо, а начали что-то придумывать?

Comment: можно еще у вас попросить ссылку, где можно почитать о добавлении в таблицу excel данных, если вам не сложно или вы могли бы написать некоторые команды, просто не могу найти не где

Comment: @grabhar не совсем понимаю о каких командах идет речь. Если у вас возникли какие-либо проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.